# Upgrading curl in Centos 5.6

Tags: centos, upgrade, curl

There is any easy way to upgrade the default curl 7.15 to the 7.20 or 7.21 version? Any repository to install into YUM.

Edit: I found this repository with the last version

http://nervion.us.es/city-fan/yum-repo/rhel5/i386/

Answer (score 2):

The curl project site has RPM files for Redhat Enterprise Linux 5, which will work just fine on your CentOS5.6 box:

http://curl.haxx.se/download.html

You will want to get both the curl and libcurl packages, along (possibly) with libcurl-dev.

Note that you will run into some dependency errors, i.e., a number of things may depend on libcurl.so.3.

Answer (score 2):

There is an even better repository here: 
http://mirror.city-fan.org/ftp/contrib/sysutils/Mirroring/

Answer (score 0):

The next repository has the last version, you can add it to YUM easily and update.

http://nervion.us.es/city-fan/yum-repo/rhel5/i386/